# How can I switch values between columns for specific rows?

Tags: r, if-statement

I was building my data set for some accounting work and accidentally made a mistake. I'd like to switch every instance of a Credit (column `journalItemLine_creditAmount`) in the account `3605` to a Debit (column `journalItemLine_debitAmount`) and every instance of a Debit to a Credit.

```
data<-read.csv(file.choose(),head=TRUE)  
fixed_data<-if(data$journalItemLine_account=="3605"){journalItemLine_debitAmount==journalItemLine_creditAmount}
fixed_data<-if(data$journalItemLine_account=="3605"){journalItemLine_creditAmount==journalItemLine_debitAmount}
```

Here's the error I'm getting.
`Error: unexpected '=' in "  fixed_data<-if(data$journalItemLine_account="`

Comment: You have swapped `=` and `==`. The test for equality in the if-statement should use `==` operator, and the assignment operator in the section in brackets should either be `=` or `<-`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't look at this closely enough. That first correction will not fully solve your problem since you want to evaluate the if-statement for each row of the data frame. You will need to use indexed logical or ifelse() for that. Don't have time to answer now but hopefully someone else will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need example data to verify, but `transform` should work too:

```
new_data <- transform(fixed_data, 
                      journalItemLine_debitAmount = ifelse(data$journalItemLine_account=="3605", journalItemLine_creditAmount, journalItemLine_debitAmount),
                      journalItemLine_creditAmount = ifelse(data$journalItemLine_account=="3605", journalItemLine_debitAmount, journalItemLine_creditAmount))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cueing off of @qdread's comments, you have a few problems:

1. `if (a=1) ...` fails because you are *assigning*, when you should be testing equality. Use `if (a==1) ...` instead.
2. `if` requires its conditional to be exactly length 1, but that will only be the case if your frame has 1 row; 0 or more than 2 will give you a warning: *"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"*. Instead, use `ifelse(condition, then, else)`.
3. Your reassignment should likely go into a column of the frame. Your `fixed_data` is a vector (which is fine) but is not actually present in the frame afterwards. In actuality, the `ifelse` recommended in #2 above doesn't know or care about frames, it just operates on vectors, so the "conditional", "then" (if true), and "else" (if false) arguments all need to be vectors of the same length (or length 1, recycled).

Your code should then look something like this (untested):

```r
data <- read.csv(file.choose(), head = TRUE)
newcred <- ifelse(data$journalItemLine_account == "3605",
                  data$journalItemLine_debitAmount, data$journalItemLine_creditAmount)
newdebt <- ifelse(data$journalItemLine_account == "3605",
                  data$journalItemLine_creditAmount, data$journalItemLine_debitAmount)
data$journalItemLine_creditAmount <- newcred
data$journalItemLine_debitAmount  <- newdebt
```

(Again, **untested!**, please verify the changes before using this on all data.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It uses a logical index to get the values of interest.

```
inx <- data$journalItemLine_account == "3605"

tmp <- data$journalItemLine_debitAmount[inx]
data$journalItemLine_debitAmount[inx] <- data$journalItemLine_creditAmount[inx]
data$journalItemLine_creditAmount[inx] <- tmp
```

Final cleanup.

```
rm(inx, tmp)
```